# Matrix sums along rows and columns

Tags: matrices

I have two vectors $x$ and $y$ of length $m$ and $n$ respectively.

I'm trying to determine whether a matrix $N$ of dimension $(m \times n)$ exists, such that the sum along its i'th row is equal to $x_i$ and the sum along every column $j$ (possibly with elements weighted by $\omega_{ij}$) is *equal to or greater than* $y_j$

Can anyone give me some pointers?

Answer (score 1):

The matrix may not exist, for instance if $\mathbf{x} = (0,0)$ and $\mathbf{y} = (1,1)$.

To try to find a solution in the general case (with exact equality to the $y_j$), I would go about it as follows. We want to find an $m \times n$ matrix $N$ such that
$$\begin{matrix}
n\left\{ \vphantom{\begin{pmatrix}
\mathbf{1}_m & \mathbf{0}_m & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \mathbf{0}_m \\
\mathbf{0}_m & \mathbf{1}_m & \mathbf{0}_m & \cdots & \cdots & \mathbf{0}_m \\
\cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots \\
\mathbf{0}_m & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \mathbf{0}_m & \mathbf{1}_m \end{pmatrix}} \right. \\
m\left\{ \vphantom{\begin{pmatrix}
1 & \mathbf{0}_{m-1} & 1 & \mathbf{0}_{m-1} & \cdots & \cdots\\
0 & 1 & \mathbf{0}_{m-1} & 1 & \mathbf{0}_{m-1} & \cdots \\
\cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots \\
\mathbf{0}_{m-1} & 1 & \cdots & \cdots & \mathbf{0}_{m-1} & 1
\end{pmatrix}} \right.
\end{matrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\mathbf{1}_m & \mathbf{0}_m & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \mathbf{0}_m \\
\mathbf{0}_m & \mathbf{1}_m & \mathbf{0}_m & \cdots & \cdots & \mathbf{0}_m \\
\cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots \\
\mathbf{0}_m & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \mathbf{0}_m & \mathbf{1}_m \\
1 & \mathbf{0}_{m-1} & 1 & \mathbf{0}_{m-1} & \cdots & \cdots\\
0 & 1 & \mathbf{0}_{m-1} & 1 & \mathbf{0}_{m-1} & \cdots \\
\cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots \\
\mathbf{0}_{m-1} & 1 & \cdots & \cdots & \mathbf{0}_{m-1} & 1
\end{pmatrix} \text{vec}(N)
= \begin{pmatrix} \mathbf{x} \\ \mathbf{y}
\end{pmatrix}$$
where $\text{vec}(N)$ is the vectorization of $N$ obtained by stacking its columns together, and $\mathbf{0}_k$ and $\mathbf{1}_k$ are the row vectors of zeros and ones of size $k$ respectively. The left-hand matrix is known, of size $(n+m, nm)$, and so is the right-hand vector of size $(n+m)$, so it remains only to find a solution to this problem now written in standard form $Ax = b$ with $A$ and $b$ known, where the unknown $x$ stands for $\text{vec}(N)$. Use any solver (eg Matlab, NumPy, SymPy) to find a solution (if it exists).

Answer (score 1):

The general case will be as difficult as solving a linear system of $m+n$ equations.

For a special case with all entries of $y$ are positive, and the sum of entries of $x$ is at least the sum of entries of $y$, let
$$m_{ij}=x_i \cdot \frac{y_j}{\sum\limits_{k=1}^n y_k}, \ \ 1\leq i\leq m,  \ \ 1\leq j\leq n.$$